# Add marker to Librosa Waveplot Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, marker, librosa

I've been following tutorials and examples from the Librosa documentation. I've managed to create a waveplot, but I can't figure out the correlation between waveplot and matplotlib. However I try to add a marker, it doesn't work. I just get a variety of different errors. I would really appreciate if someone knows how to do this?

BTW: Any mp3 can be used to test this code

```
import librosa.display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = 'shut_up_and_dance.mp3'


def main():
    # Load the mp3 file and define variables
    y, sr = librosa.load(filename, duration=10)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, sharex=True, sharey=True)
    

    y_harm, y_perc = librosa.effects.hpss(y)
    librosa.display.waveplot(y_harm, sr=sr, alpha=0.25, ax=ax)
    librosa.display.waveplot(y_perc, sr=sr, color='r', alpha=0.5, ax=ax)
    ax.set(title='Harmonic + Percussive')
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

print('end program')
```

Comment: Trying to do something like in these examples. But nothing seems to work. https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/marker_reference.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Libra.display.waveplot()` does not, as far as I can tell, have the ability to set markers. I have no knowledge of sound waveforms. I don't know what output I want, but matplotlib seems to be able to handle it.

```
import librosa.display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

filename = '/content/test_music.mp3'

def main():
    # Load the mp3 file and define variables
    y, sr = librosa.load(filename, duration=10)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(16,9))

    y_harm, y_perc = librosa.effects.hpss(y)
    librosa.display.waveplot(y_harm, sr=sr, alpha=0.25, ax=ax)
    librosa.display.waveplot(y_perc, sr=sr, color='r', alpha=0.5, ax=ax)
    ax.set(title='Harmonic + Percussive')
    ax.plot(np.arange(1,220501), y_harm, marker='o', markersize=10)
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: This worked! Can I bother you to explain how that line worked? I understand the marker and markersize attributes. but I dont understand how the markers are placed, or why they are connected by a line.

Comment: My code gets the length of the x-axis, which is 220500, so I set it up and created a line graph with your retrieved `y_harm` as the y-axis, with a round marker. This is just a sample, so it depends on what kind of marker you want to put on it. [Examples of Markers](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/marker_reference.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-marker-reference-py)